# How would one find the product of given numbers with a while loop?

Tags: java

I am asked to do the follow question -

Write a Java program that uses a while statement to prompt the user to enter 6 integer numbers.
Your program should print the product of the numbers entered when the loop ends.

```
   Example output
   Product of four numbers
   Enter a number: 2
   Enter a number: 2
   Enter a number: 2
   Enter a number: 2
   Product equals 16
```

I've attempted the question with the following code: `

```
    //declaring variables
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, result;

    //prompting user
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num1 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num2 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num3 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num4 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num5 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num6 = scanner.nextInt();

    //calculations
    result = num1*num2*num3*num4*num5*num6;

    //output
    System.out.println("The product of your numbers entered are: " + result);

}
```

}`

However I **MUST** use a while loop, how would I incorporate that?

Comment: use an array of size six, have an int `i`, loop `while (i < numarr.length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the while loop by multiplying a result variable each time by the entered number from the user using a counter and break the loop when it's loop 6 times

```
int counter = 0;
int result = 1;

while (counter < 6) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    result = result * number;
    counter++;
}

System.out.println("The product of your numbers entered are: " + result);
```

Comment: while the answer is correct, code dumping a ready answer is not the purpose of this site, it would be better the *describe* the answer and let OP arrive at the solution